# Doing a recursive query in SQL to get data in cascade

Tags: sql, recursive-query

Think in an scenario where you have a table of users. The users have a role assigned and a referer field which is the ID of other user with a higher role. Let's assume that we have 5 roles having the fifth the higher one. The referer id is always the ID of the user who has added this user and it only can be in one role higher

I want to get all the users who are below the role 5 ( starting with the role 4 ) but they must be refered by the user or a user who has been refered by my user and so on. Example:

```
User1: [ role: 5, referer: 0 (because is the first user), id: 1]
User2: [ role: 4, referer: 1, id:2]
User3: [ role: 4, referer: 44, id: 3]
User4: [ role: 3, referer: 2, id: 4]
User6: [ role: 2, referer: 4, id: 5]
User7: [ role: 1, referer: 5, id: 6]
User8: [ role: 1, referer: 44, id: 7]
```

So I want to query using the User1 data and the response should have the User2, User4, User6, User7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Help us help you - please tag your question with the [tag:rdbms] you're using and add the table's structure and the the source data that should be used to produce this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `recursive CTE`

```
with cte as
(Select * from tbl where id=1
union all 
Select u.id, u.role,u.referer from tbl u
join cte c on c.id = u.referer
)
Select * from cte where role <(Select role from tbl where id=1)
```

Comment: Unrecognized statement type. (near "with" at position 0)

Comment: what's your rdbms?

Comment: I'm using MySQL, InnoDB

Comment: Damn, I'm on version 5.7, I'm going to upgrade mysql and tell you if it worked. Anyways thanks for your help